# Tkinter images crashing

Tags: python, image, tkinter

So I made a script in python with Tkinter and the thing is that the first Tkinter window pops up without problems but when the code goes to the second window it says :

> _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

and I didn't find anything that helped me, could someone help me please ?
Here is the code :

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def choose():
    global name, chosen
    name = name1.get()
    chosen = chosen1.get()
    print name
    print chosen
    root0.quit()

root0 = Tk()
name1 = Entry(root0)
name1.pack()
chosen1 = Entry(root0)
chosen1.pack()
Button(root0, text="ENTER", command=choose).pack()
root0.mainloop()

root = Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('person1.png'))
panel1 = Label(root, image = img)
panel1.pack(side="left")
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('person2.png'))
panel2 = Label(root, image = img2)
panel2.pack(side="right")
root.mainloop()
```

by the way, the python version is 2.7

Answer (score 0):

This is a side effect of using 2 roots (`Tk()` instances). The images default to associate with the first root window. The quick fix is to provide the image with the correct root:

```
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('person2.png'), master=root)
```

The proper fix is to never use more than one `Tk()`. Put all your code into Frame instances, and then destroy one and load the other when the time is right:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def choose():
    global name, chosen
    name = name1.get()
    chosen = chosen1.get()
    print name
    print chosen
    frame0.destroy() # kill this frame
    frame1.pack() # open new frame

root = tk.Tk()
frame0 = tk.Frame(root)
name1 = tk.Entry(frame0)
name1.pack()
chosen1 = tk.Entry(frame0)
chosen1.pack()
tk.Button(frame0, text="ENTER", command=choose).pack()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('person1.png'))
panel1 = tk.Label(frame1, image = img)
panel1.pack(side="left")
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('person2.png'))
panel2 = tk.Label(frame1, image = img2)
panel2.pack(side="right")

#start the program
frame0.pack() # load frame0
root.mainloop()
```

Note I also moved you away from the evil wildcard imports (`from module import *`).